# Search Entity by many-to-many relation and return all relations with the found Entities

Tags: many-to-many, nestjs, typeorm

I have two entities:

- Product
- Category

Product and Category have a many-to-many relation.
Looking something like this:

```js
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "a product",
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "title": "spherical"
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "title": "small"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to for example find all products which are categorized as spherical

Now I tried to join the category to my product and use "Where" to conditionally only get Products which have a Category with the matching Category id

```js
async findProductsByCategory(id: number): Promise<Product[]> {
    const products = await this.productRepository
    .createQueryBuilder("product")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("product.categories", "category")
    .where("category.id =:id", {id: id})
    .getMany();
    return products;
}
```

This only works partly.
Example searching for products in category 6 :

```js
    {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "a product",
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "title": "spherical"
        }
    ]
    },
    {
    "id": 7,
    "title": "another product",
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "title": "spherical"
        }
    ]
    }
```

It returns only the Products I want to see, but it also only includes the Category relation which I used as condition.

Can someone help me find all Products with a certain Category relation AND return them with all of their Category relations ?

**EDIT: simplified my example**

**EDIT: I found a Workaround and submitted it as answer, I will still wait in case someone has a better solution to my question**

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the problem by first making a query to get all the products I am looking for, just to get their id and after that making a new query in which I get those products by id and join all their categories to them

```js
    async findProductByCategory(id: number): Promise<Product[]> {
    
    const subQueryResults = await this.productRepository
        .createQueryBuilder("product")
        .select("product.id")
        .innerJoin("product.categories", "category", "category.id = :id", {id:id})
        .getMany();

        const products = await this.productRepository
        .createQueryBuilder("product")
        .where("product.id IN (:...subQuery)", {subQuery: subQueryResults.map(a => a.id)})
        .innerJoinAndSelect("product.categories", "category")
        .getMany();

        return products;
}
```